# How to send JSON as a Input parameter from one Microservice to another using RestTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, microservices

I want to send `JSON` as an `input` from Microservice M1 to a Microservice M2.

M1 and M2 both are on different machines.
I am new to Spring Boot,

I found some [code](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) but I am unable to get it.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

make a class on both microservices or make a jar of that class and add to both microservices so that they both can access the same data.

Lets say the class is

```
class TestData{
 private String name;
 private String id;

 // getters and setters
}
```

Now you can send data from M1 to M2 as following

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    TestData data = new TestData();
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(data,headers);
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity =    restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
```

In Microservice M2 you can write a controller to get the data and process it as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Object do(@RequestBody TestData data){
  // do something
  return //something
}
```

Comment: Hello i implemented the same code as you posted above.

Comment: I am facing authentication failure error. do i need to set username and password of other system on which the M2 Microservice is running. if so how to set that

Comment: in that case you need to provide a mechanism for calling micro service to make an authenticated call to m2 so that m2 can authenticate call and do stuff. it actually depends what auth mechanism you have used

Comment: RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     //headers.add("Authorization","");
     
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
     TestData data = new TestData();

     HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(data,headers);
     ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://10.109.218.178:9090/loadJson", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);

Comment: i meant how your application at 10.109.218.178 handles authentication. You can make this url public to test and then apply authentication. if its based on header's authorixzation then, pass correct key value in authorization field of headers

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh what EkanshRastogi means is that you implemented either Springs basic auth (username and password) or maybe you used an api key or maybe something else. depending on that method you need to implement it differently in your M1 code. But we need to know what is first before we can tell you how it's done

Answer (score 0):

Let's Say Your Have MicroService1 which needs to send JSONObject => JsonObject to another MicroService2 which is on different Machine but on same network .

Sender Side:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    

String jsonString = restTemplate.postForObject("http://10.177.7.128:8080/user/insertJsonObject",jsonObject,String.class);
```

Syntax for restTemplate.postForObject is:

```
ResponseType var1 =   restTemplate.postForObject("network ip Address:portnumber/path",JSONObject,ResponseType)
```

To Know the URI go to System Preferences > Network

To Receive the object at the receiver Side

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/insertJsonObject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updateProductSold(@RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject) { 

...Body
...
...

return responseStatus;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"id\" : \"123\",\"name\" : \"Tom\",\"class\" : {\"subject\" : \"Math\",\"teacher\" : \"Jack\"}}";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://192.1168.1.190:8080/test" // url for second service
        System.out.println(responserEntityValue(jsonString,restTemplate,url,HttpMethod.POST,String.class));
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> responserEntityValue(final String body, final RestTemplate restTemplate,
            final String uRL, final HttpMethod requestMethod, final Class<String> stringClass) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // Set all headers
        headers.add(DatabaseConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        return restTemplate.exchange(uRL, requestMethod, request, stringClass);

    }
```